# Get current Virtual Desktop - number/name/tag/id?

Tags: xorg, kde, window-manager

How to get number and/or name (or tag/id... etc) of currently used virtual desktop ?

Command line, scripting, C/C++ solutions allowed (, while portable to C/C++ are preferred). ;)

I'm mostly interested in `KDE` and `GNOME`, as well as [`dwm`](http://dwm.suckless.org/), [`xmonad`](http://xmonad.org/), [`awesome`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) - solutions for other desktop environments are welcome (I would love to support as much as I can, in order to provide as universal solution as possible).

Btw. For those interested, To be more specific about usecase: I'm interested in timetracking oriented around desktop + windows focus + xevents + multiplescreen. Currently there exist separate solutions for this ([`ktimetracker`](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/ktimetracker/) tracks tasks depending on desktops, while it's app tracking is very poor - no regular expressions support, just exact window titles -> not very usefull. On the other hand, [`workrave`](http://www.workrave.org/) tracks keyboard and mouse activity, but is unaware of desktop->task I work on.), I'd like to do something, that merges those information in order to achieve more precise picture (maybe incorporating [Association rule learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) or other [Data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining) technique) of activities I have (in order to achieve more precise information related with my habits, in order with "ant-[RSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury) fight" ;) ).

So if your desktop follows in different paradigm, than "Virtual Desktop + Windows (with Names and Titles)" please, show code/cli snippet, that shows information about currently used window/frame/app + currently selected desktop/task/tags (eventually screen).

Comment: A general solution to this is not going to be possible. For example the Desktop Environment I use doesn't use VD's at all, it uses tags that can be mixed and matched at any given moment. There are ways that will span a few DE's, but don't expect full coverage.

Comment: Thanks @Celeb , I hope you don't mind, I've changed a little bit problem statement, according to your comment. Thanks for pointing me - I hope - on right way. :)

Comment: Of that list, I know `awesome` is going to play a different game. That's why I use and is the one that specifically handles VD's using an entirely different paradigm. I think `xmonad` and `dwm` are much like it. They are known as dynamic or framework managers and don't have the kind of desktop paradigm that Gnome/KDE based WM's typically do. You can probably come up with something that works across stock Gnome/KDE/XFCE ... however I would seriously question whether you are on the right track at all. It sounds like you are trying to work this problem backwards.

Comment: As far as your program is concerned, Window Managers should be left to their job however they want their job to be done, meddling with the WM from inside a program is not welcome. If you are trying to add functionality / behavior to a WM or write some kind of window controller / monitor, this will need to be done specific to each different WM and use the WM's own API, whatever that is.

Comment: Hello, @Celeb your comments inspired me to write more about my motivations putting me into this question. As you guessed, I'd like to monitor. Because monitor is not oriented to receive "well structured data", but "any structured data" in order to do some mining on that, I am open for paradigm differences. I just would like to reason about user task according to his/her current behaviour. Current desktop configuration (like selected virtual desktop ,tag or sth) is great source of informatino what is beeing done at moment. For example: I named my VD's for this purpose.

Comment: A similar project that might be interesting to you is [`arbtt`](http://darcs.nomeata.de/arbtt/doc/users_guide/): *"arbtt is a background daemon that stores which windows are open, which one has the focus and how long since your last action (and possibly more sources later), and stores this. It is also a program that will, based on expressive rules you specify, derive what you were doing, and what for."*

Comment: @sr_ arbtt is a great tool :D. Why haven't you put it as separate answer, but as comment? - it deserves it :) (and points). I'have to check out it's sources carefully :).

Comment: added an answer with a little additional information :)

Answer (score 5):

Window managers that adhere to the [FreeDesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/) standards store information about desktops in [properties of the root window](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html), in particular:

- `_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS`: number of virtual desktops
- `_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP`: index of the active desktop
- `_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES`: list of names of the virtual desktops

You can access these with any interface to [`XGetWindowProperty`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XListProperties.3.xhtml) such as [`xprop`](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xprop.1.xhtml). From the shell, [`wmctrl -d`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) provides a handy way of listing the virtual desktops.

As far as I know, only the window manager is notified when a property of the root window changes. So if you want to react to virtual desktop switching, you'll have to work with the window manager. For example, with your use case, I'd use the Lisp hooks provided by my window manager ([Sawfish](http://sawfish.wikia.com/)) when anything interesting happens.

Comment: thanks for precise stuff, I need a moment to look carefully at this. All things you've mentioned looks relevant, interesting and useful. Please, give me some time before I evaluate answer :).

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at [`arbtt`](http://darcs.nomeata.de/arbtt/doc/users_guide/), the *Automatic Rule-Base Time Tracker* written mainly by [Joachim Breitner](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/projects#arbtt) in [Haskell](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell).  [See the config example for a peak of what it's able to do,](http://darcs.nomeata.de/arbtt/doc/users_guide/configuration.html#id3725163) i.e., tracking your work time via focused window titles and time rules. (Maybe more, I have never tried it; no use case here, but it sounds similar to what you try to do.)

It's available [via hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arbtt) and [on Debian's repositories](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=arbtt).

Comment: `arbtt` looks like very similar project, I'd like to do. Thanks for it. It's always good to compare to similar existing applications, in order to check what other people implement as important :).